# What kind of t-test?

Tags: classification, t-test

I have 3 algorithms (A, B, C) which predict "author name" of each text article. I have tested all the algorithms on 3 different corpora (X, Y, Z) (different number of articles from 3 newspapers). I have got the following result.

The result provides the number of "Correct" and "Incorrect" answers and the "Accuracy" (correct_answer/total) for each Algorithm on each Corpus:

```
Algorithm A =>    Corpus X: 80%,    Corpus Y: 93%,    Corpus Z: 94%
Algorithm B =>    Corpus X: 78%,    Corpus Y: 90%,    Corpus Z: 89%
Algorithm C =>    Corpus X: 90%,    Corpus Y: 83%,    Corpus Z: 97%
```

I have to compare the results by T-test and sign-test in order to define which one is the best algorithm. But I do not know which kind of T-test I have to use (independent, two-tailed, paired…).

Also I have heard that I have to use one-way ANOVA instead of t-test.

Comment: I could imagine a one-way ANOVA with just three observations in each group, the "groups" being the three algorithms, BUT the three "errors" in one group don't seem really independent since the same three corpora are used all three times.  And the corpora may not be a random sample from any population.  So corpora are "crossed" with algorithms, rather than "nested" within algorithms.  I'd also want to know how big the samples were: is the 80% four out of five, or maybe 80 out of 100?  So maybe just shoving this into a standard algorithm isn't the best thing to do.

Comment: @Michael Hardy, thank you for your comment.
I think I have to explain more:
I think the corpora are independent since each corpus has different articles from different authors. They are analyzed independently by each algorithm (separately). Corpus X has 10 articles, Y has 2000 articles and Z has 1500 articles. I do not have any idea about "crossed" and "nested". Remember that, I need to find out the "Best Algorithm".